# Docker RabbitMQ Message disappear on restart

Tags: c#, docker, rabbitmq

I use this command line new RabbitMQ container

```
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 --name rabbitmq --hostname rabbitmq rabbitmq:management
```

Code setting durable:true, then restart container queue is exists, message is disappeared

```
channel.QueueDeclare(
    queue: name,        
    durable: true,      
    exclusive: false,   
    autoDelete: false,  
    arguments: null     
);
```

[image]

Please ask what question? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html):

> When RabbitMQ quits or crashes it will forget the queues and messages
> unless you tell it not to. Two things are required to make sure that
> messages aren't lost: we need to mark both the queue and messages as
> durable.

So you need something like this:

```
var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
properties.Persistent = true;

channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                     routingKey: "task_queue",
                     basicProperties: properties,
                     body: body);
```

Comment: how messages setting durable ?

Comment: @GrapeWater I've already added an example into my comment. Also check the link I put into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any publish?

```
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                             routingKey: "hello",
                             basicProperties: null,
                             body: body);
```

Ref: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

Comment: publish use channel.BasicPublish("", name, null, body)